# How can I recover the controlling tty after a setsid

Tags: c, linux

After a `fork()` I do a setsid to create a new session. But when I do that I cannot use programs that use termcaps like emacs.
It does the error `"emacs: Could not open file: /dev/tty".`

How can I recover the control on /dev/tty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ioctl( fd, TIOCSCTTY )`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl):

> **TIOCSCTTY**
>
> **int** *arg*
>
> Make the given terminal the controlling terminal of the calling
>   process. The calling process must be a session leader and not have a
>   controlling terminal already. If this terminal is already the
>   controlling terminal of a different session group then the ioctl fails
>   with EPERM, unless the caller is root (more precisely: has the
>   CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability) and arg equals 1, in which case the terminal
>   is stolen, and all processes that had it as controlling terminal lose
>   it.
>
> **void**
>
> If the given terminal was the controlling terminal of the calling
>   process, give up this controlling terminal. If the process was session
>   leader, then send SIGHUP and SIGCONT to the foreground process group
>   and all processes in the current session lose their controlling
>   terminal.

Lots of caveats apply.  Read this blog post titled ["Reptyr: Changing a Process's Controlling Terminal"](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/02/changing-ctty/) and look at the code referenced.  That code transplants a process from one terminal to another and may do exactly what you need.